# Problema para ejecutar los scripts

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

Estoy llamando a un JSP desde un servlet, cuando ejecuta funciona todo bien, pero los scripts no funcionan.

Estoy llamando de la siguiente manera al jsp:

```
  RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Registro.jsp");
           rd.forward(request, response);
```

El jsp es una pagina html con sus scripts.

Pero no me hace las llamadas a las funciones, nada.

Comment: Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Podrias editar la pregunta y agregar el jsp de la pagina q estas llamando para ver como lo estas haciendo